# How to set initial value for useState hook using props?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am getting undefined as value for 'num'. But its working fine when using local variable.
How to solve this issue?

props :

```
spec = {
 id: 32,
 itemCode: {number: 10000002, __typename: "ItemCode"},
 product: 600004,
 spec_class: "DS",
 grade: "DEFAULT",
}
```

Component

```
<ItemCodeSpecForm initialData={spec} />

function ItemCodeSpecForm(props){
    console.log(props)
    const { number } = useParams();
    const itemCode = parseInt(number);
    const [open, setOpen] =useState(false)
    const [l, setL] = useState(true? 'm':"n")
    const [num, setNum] = useState(props.initialData  ? props.initialData.id : 2)
    return (
        <div>
            {props.initialData && console.log(props.initialData.id)}
            {console.log('num',num)}
            {console.log(l)}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Can you please share how you are passing the props to `ItemCodeSpecForm` component? Maybe you are missing out something there. Thanks!

Comment: `const [num, setNum] = useState(props.initialData  ? props.initialData.id : 2)` - if you're getting undefined then it means that your props.initialData exists, but does not have a .id value.  What are the props that you're passing here?

Comment: I have added the Props in the question. And id is there in the props. @SethLutske

Comment: @norbitrial Please look into the code now. I have added the props.

Comment: Do you see the proper values from `console.log(props)` step on the console?

Comment: @norbitrial yes. Thats ok. Do you have any example of using conditional props in default value of useState?

Comment: Just tested out your example and working like charm, showing on the console `num 32`. Where do you define `spec` to pass to `initialData` attribute? Maybe that's where the trick is hiding. Can you please post the whole component where you are using `ItemCodeSpecForm` component?